# How does inserting $N$ objects one at a time into an ordered AVL tree yield an efficient sorting algorithim

Tags: algorithms, trees

If we assume reblalancing an AVL tree of height n after an insertion or deletion takes $O(n)$ operations.

How does inserting $N$ objects one at a time into an ordered AVL tree yield an efficient sorting algorithm?

Comment: This might be more appropriate on a computer science forum...

Comment: Knowing that rebalancing is O(h), and that AVL trees guarantee that h is O(log N), what can you say about the asymptotic behavior of sorting N objects via insertion into the tree?

Comment: does it follow log N ? I'm very new to this